# Salesforce subscribe topic

Tags: salesforce, mule

I've got 2 SalesForce connectors subscribing on /ContactTopic & /AccountTopic.

Now when I check my log files I notice that, after 19 hours of runtime (application is running on mule enterprise), I've got 5 subscribes on each topic.

```
INFO  2015-01-14 08:05:16,403 [HttpClient-517] org.mule.modules.salesforce.SalesforceBayeuxClient: Re-Subscribing to channel: /topic/AccountTopic
INFO  2015-01-14 08:05:16,485 [HttpClient-517] org.mule.modules.salesforce.SalesforceBayeuxClient: Re-Subscribing to channel: /topic/ContactTopic
INFO  2015-01-14 08:05:17,067 [HttpClient-1363] org.mule.modules.salesforce.SalesforceBayeuxClient: Re-Subscribing to channel: /topic/AccountTopic
INFO  2015-01-14 08:05:17,149 [HttpClient-1363] org.mule.modules.salesforce.SalesforceBayeuxClient: Re-Subscribing to channel: /topic/ContactTopic
INFO  2015-01-14 08:06:11,247 [HttpClient-601] org.mule.modules.salesforce.SalesforceBayeuxClient: Re-Subscribing to channel: /topic/AccountTopic
INFO  2015-01-14 08:06:11,329 [HttpClient-601] org.mule.modules.salesforce.SalesforceBayeuxClient: Re-Subscribing to channel: /topic/ContactTopic
INFO  2015-01-14 08:06:17,231 [HttpClient-1576] org.mule.modules.salesforce.SalesforceBayeuxClient: Re-Subscribing to channel: /topic/AccountTopic
INFO  2015-01-14 08:06:17,313 [HttpClient-1576] org.mule.modules.salesforce.SalesforceBayeuxClient: Re-Subscribing to channel: /topic/ContactTopic
INFO  2015-01-14 08:06:19,451 [HttpClient-1603] org.mule.modules.salesforce.SalesforceBayeuxClient: Re-Subscribing to channel: /topic/AccountTopic
INFO  2015-01-14 08:06:19,533 [HttpClient-1603] org.mule.modules.salesforce.SalesforceBayeuxClient: Re-Subscribing to channel: /topic/ContactTopic
```

After the subscribe I simply use a datamapper to insert everything into a MYSQL database.

Is this a bug in Mule or am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That log file doesn't necessarily means you have 5 subscribers. If there is any problem with the connection the suscription will be reconnected, and that could explain your re-subscriptions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. Well, I think there are 5 of them because i  get 5 new records in my MYSQL database each time an Account / Contact gets updated. (All 5 have the same data)

Comment: intersting, could you please share the relevant pieces of your xml config?

Answer (score 0):

I've finally solved it. Something very stupid, I was subscribing on API 29, while my application was using 31.. I think this way it couldn't re-subscribe properly on a 'expire' notification. In any case, it is working right now. Thanks!